# inequalities problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

**The problem:**

> Solve the inequality $$\frac{5}{(x^2 - 4x)} < \frac{18}{(x^2 - 16)} + \frac{-9}{(x+4)} \cdot 119$$

My answer:
[ANSWER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mttj.jpg)

Could you please help me find my mistake?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: You have taken the numerator and denominator separately and put them less than zero. But, if both are less than zero then the quotient is greater than zero, which is the opposite of what you want. So take two cases- (1)numerator>0, denominator<0 and (2)numerator<0, denominator>0. Then quotient is greater than zero.

Comment: thank you very much!!